# Adding Many (UDFs) Validation Functions to Oracle - Which Method Run Fastest

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, plsql

I have to move around 50+ validation functions into Oracle.  I'm looking for the approach that runs fastest, but also would like to get around a `boolean` issue if possible.  The return object for them all needs to be the same so that the application can react off the result in a consistent fashion and alert the user or display whatever popups, messages we may need.  I created a `valObj` for this, but not sure yet if that is the best approach.  The return format can be changed because the front-end that reacts off of it is not developed yet.  In the end it will contain many different validation functions, from integer, number, phone, email, IPv4, IPv6, etc...  This is what I have so far...

```
/***
This is the validation object.
It stores 1 for valid, 0 for not valid and some helper text that can be relayed back to the user.
***/
create or replace type valObj as object (
    result number(1),
    resultText varchar(32000)
);

/***
Coming from ColdFusion this seems clean to me but the function
will end up being a couple thousand lines long.
***/
create or replace function isValid(v in varchar2, format in varchar2)
return valObj
is
  test number;
begin
if format = 'number' then
    begin
        test := to_number(v);
        return valObj(1,null);
        exception when VALUE_ERROR then return valObj(0,'Invalid number. Valid formats are: 12345, 12345.67, -12345, etc...');
    end;
elsif format = 'integer' then
    null; --TO DO
elsif format = 'email' then
    null; --TO DO
elsif format = 'IPv4' then
    null; --TO DO
elsif format = 'IPv6' then
    null; --TO DO
end if;
--dozens of others to follow....
end;
/

/* Example Usage in SQL */
select isValid('blah','number') from dual; -- returns: (0, Invalid number. Valid formats are: 12345, 12345.67, -12345, etc...)
select isValid('blah','number').result from dual; -- returns: 0
select isValid('blah','number').resulttext from dual; -- returns: Valid formats are: 12345, 12345.67, -12345, etc...
select isValid(1234567890.123,'number') from dual; -- returns: 1,{null}
select isValid(1234567890.123,'number').result from dual; -- returns: 1
select isValid(1234567890.123,'number').resulttext from dual; -- returns: {null}

/* Example Usage in PL/SQL */
declare
temp valObj;
begin
    temp := isValid('blah','number');
    if (temp.result = 0) then
        dbms_output.put_line(temp.resulttext);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Valid');
    end if;
end;
/
```

My questions are:

1. When using it in PL/SQL I would love to be able to do `boolean` checks instead like this: `if (temp.result) then` but I can't figure out a way, cause that won't work in SQL.  Should I just add a 3rd boolean attribute to the `valObj` or is there another way I don't know of?
2. These validation functions could end up being called within large loops.  Knowing that, is this the most efficient way to accomplish these validations?

I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I forgot about `MEMBER FUNCTIONS`.  Thanks @Brian McGinity for reminding me.  So I'd like to go with this method since it keeps the `type` and its `functions` encapsulated together.  **Would there be any speed difference between this method and a stand-alone function?  Would this be compiled and stored the same as a stand-alone function?**

```
create or replace type isValid as object (
    result     number(1),
    resulttext varchar2(32000),
    constructor function isValid(v varchar, format varchar) return self as result );
/

create or replace type body isValid as
    constructor function isValid(v varchar, format varchar) return self as result as
        test number;
    begin
        if format = 'number' then
            begin
                test := to_number(v);
                self.result := 1;
                self.resulttext := null;
                return;
                exception when VALUE_ERROR then
                    self.result := 0;
                    self.resulttext := 'Invalid number. Valid formats are: 12345, 12345.67, -12345, etc...';
                    return;
            end;
        elsif format = 'phone' then
            null; --TO DO
        end if;
        --and many others...
    end;
end;
/

/* Example Usage in SQL */
select isValid('a','number') from dual;

/* Example Usage in PL/SQL */
declare
begin
    if (isValid('a','number').result = 1) then
        null;
    end if;
end;
/
```

**TEST RESULTS:**

```
/* Test isValid (the object member function), this took 7 seconds to run */
declare
begin
    for i in 1 .. 2000000 loop
        if (isValid('blah','number').result = 1) then
            null;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;

/* Test isValid2 (the stand-alone function), this took 16 seconds to run */
declare
begin
    for i in 1 .. 2000000 loop
        if (isValid2('blah','number').result = 1) then
            null;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

Both `isValid` and `isValid2` do the same exact code, they just run this line `test := to_number(v);` then do the exception if it fails and return the result.  Does this appear to be a valid test?  The Object member function method is actually faster than a stand-alone function???

Comment: Functions are compiled in Database, and its execution speed is very fast, when no `TABLE` references are made (No SQLs). And with respect to `boolean` , You have to specify both operands for comparison like `true` or `false`. `boolean` benefits you _only_ in terms of memory usage. And then, both your approaches are same as it appears to me. Even when called in Loops, should not be an issue.(If only constants you deal with inside)

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, they are pretty much the same.  Yes, I'm aware if there is SQL (a query) in a validation function  it will slow it down.  I'm also trying to get them to change `PLSQL_CODE_TYPE` to NATIVE: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/plsql-new-features-and-enhancements-11gr1.php#native_compilation "Remember, native compilation will improve the speed of procedure code, but has no effect on the performance of SQL."  But packages are compiled in the DB as well, you still think the single large function would be faster?

Comment: yes,the size of the function should not matter much, because, after first execution, it would be in oracle's closest memory unless it is rarely called. And consecutive calls would not end up in loading the function to memory, and executed immediately. Also there's something called [pinning](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7037830724934) objects to SGA. Which makes the Oracle to always have that in SGA, even if it is not frequently called. But it is not advisable to pin to SGA, unless you need it!

Comment: @OracleUser I was just reminded of another option.  If you have time look at the **UPDATE** part of the question, curious as to what your thoughts are.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 Nice one!! Am not with my PC, else would have written a stress test `PL/SQL` block and measure _time taken_ both in terms of execution time and CPU time. `Member functions` seems to be a nice plan. But you use a `OBJECT` instead of a plain function call. I think, function only call wins over the object references!!!! But not sure though..

Comment: I'd love to see your results.  I don't know how to get those two different measurements but I did run two identical PL/SQL blocks, one called the object member function 2 million times, the other called the stand-alone function.  To my surprise the object was considerably faster, 7 seconds as opposed to 16 seconds!  I'll put test code in question.

Comment: Interesting, to see 2x difference.

Comment: Wow, that is a great find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stand-alone function can be much faster if you set it to DETERMINISTIC and if the data is highly repetitive.  On my machine this setting decreased run time from 9 seconds to 0.1 seconds.  For reasons I don't understand that setting does not improve performance of the object function.

```
create or replace function isValid2(v in varchar2, format in varchar2)
return valObj
deterministic --<< Hit the turbo button!
is
  test number;
begin
if format = 'number' then
    begin
        test := to_number(v);
        return valObj(1,null);
        exception when VALUE_ERROR then return valObj(0,'Invalid number. Valid formats are: 12345, 12345.67, -12345, etc...');
    end;
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Gotta be careful with deterministic functions, use them only when the set of possible input values is small.  A 'isNumber()' validation function is a poor place for a deterministic function because there could be 10,000 to 10,000,000+ different combinations--how can oracle keep track of that?

Comment: @BrianMcGinity That's a good question, I'm not sure how Oracle caches deterministic functions in PL/SQL.  According to [this AskTom article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html) Oracle hashes 255 values for scalar subquery caching, but I'm not sure if the same algorithm applies to PL/SQL.  I've never heard of anyone encountering problems with a DETERMINISTIC function caching too much, I assume there is a limit.

Comment: Well in my tests deterministic definitely helped a lot.  And it did help with the function in the object also, so long as I passed in `x` and not `'blah'`.  It's really weird and warrants a new question, I started it here and I show my test results: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21916218/3112803  Based on those results it appears the member function way with deterministic would be best for my use cases.  Do you agree?  This answer caused the most speed increase so I'll award the answer but I think I'll use deterministic and the member function, not the stand-alone function.

Comment: Deterministic functions are designed for a much much much smaller input and result set.  They are stored in memory and duplicated for each user.  You could use it for a Male/Female or True/False validation functions. Personally I would only use it if the argument/result set was less than 100 distinct values as Oracle stores a hash map for each set of input values/result.  See this for   more info: http://allthingsoracle.com/caching-part-1/

Comment: @BrianMcGinity I think there is some confusion between function result caching and whatever is going on with deterministic functions.  I just ran a simple test on a small local database with 1 billion unique values, and the deterministic and non-deterministic both ran in the same amount of time.  I'm not sure what Oracle's algorithm is for deterministic functions but it doesn't appear to use significant resources when the number of distinct values is large.  DETERMINISTIC won't always help, but as long as it's logically valid, it never seems to hurt.

Answer (score 1):

May also want to consider utilizing pls_integer over number.  Don't know if it will buy you much, but documents suggest some gain will be had.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/03_types.htm states,
"You use the PLS_INTEGER datatype to store signed integers. Its magnitude range is -2**31 .. 2**31. PLS_INTEGER values require less storage than NUMBER values. Also, PLS_INTEGER operations use machine arithmetic, so they are faster than NUMBER and BINARY_INTEGER operations, which use library arithmetic. For efficiency, use PLS_INTEGER for all calculations that fall within its magnitude range."

Comment: That appears to be a PL/SQL datatype.  So I could only add that to the function for checking if it's a number.  I couldn't change the `result number(1);` in the object to `PLS_INTEGER`.  With the change to the function I saw no change in time with my 2 million loop test.  I'll still use it cause it makes sense, but I saw no gains.  Thanks!