# Trying to Understand Oracle Deterministic Function Speed Test Results

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql

This question arose as a spin-off from this one: [Adding Many (UDFs) Validation Functions to Oracle - Which Method Run Fastest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893989/adding-many-udfs-validation-functions-to-oracle-which-method-run-fastest)

I am debating between putting a low level function that will be used everywhere in my application in an object as a `CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION` so it's encapsulated with it's type that it returns, or just making the function `STAND-ALONE`.  I know most would thing these test result are inconsequential because the loop count is so high.  But in our app this function could be used to check multiple columns in each large loop iteration.  So it really wouldn't be hard for us to reach 3 million checks in a single process.  And this all reports back to a web page so the user is waiting on these results, so every msec matters.

So I was running some results and this is what I found...

```
/*****
isValid is a CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION of an OBJECT
and it is deterministic

passing in:
'blah'    -> 12 seconds
x         -> 464 msecs
changing x to varchar2(7)
x         -> 2 seconds (this is how we would use it in most cases within loops)
*****/
declare
x number;
--x varchar2(7);
begin
    for i in 1 .. 3000000 loop
        x := x + 1;
        if (isValid(x,'number').result = 1) then
            null;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/

/*****
isValid2 is a STAND-ALONE FUNCTION
and it is deterministic

passing in:
'blah'    -> 407 msecs
x         -> 4 seconds
changing x to varchar2(7)
x         -> 4 seconds (this is how we would use it in most cases within loops)
*****/
declare
x number;
--x varchar2(7);
begin
    for i in 1 .. 3000000 loop
        x := x + 1;
        if (isValid2(x,'number').result = 1) then
            null;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Based on these result I think I'm going to go with the `CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION of an OBJECT` approach.

**So my question is: Why are the result between `'blah'` and `x` completely reversed between the two different methods?**

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL = 2 (I've never read up on this, this is a test box, I'm not sure what it *should* be set to yet but I will read up on it)

PLSQL_CODE_TYPE = INTERPRETED (I know NATIVE is faster but they won't change it.)
```

Here is the stand-alone function...

```
create or replace type valObj as object (
    result     number(1),
    resulttext varchar2(32000) );
/

create or replace function isValid2(v in varchar2, f in varchar2)
return valObj
deterministic
is
  test PLS_INTEGER;
begin
    if f = 'number' then
        begin
            test := to_number(v);
            return valObj(1,null);
            exception when VALUE_ERROR then return valObj(0,'Invalid number. Valid formats are: 12345, 12345.67, -12345, etc...');
        end;
    elsif f = 'phone' then
        null; --TO DO
    elsif f = 'integer' then
        null; --TO DO
    elsif f = 'email' then
        null; --TO DO
    elsif f = 'IPv4' then
        null; --TO DO
    elsif f = 'IPv6' then
        null; --TO DO
    end if;
    --dozens of others to follow....
end;
/
```

And here is the object/function...

```
create or replace type isValid as object (
    result     number(1),
    resulttext varchar2(32000),
    constructor function isValid(v varchar, f varchar) return self as result deterministic );
/

create or replace type body isValid as
    constructor function isValid(v varchar, f varchar) return self as result deterministic is
        test PLS_INTEGER;
    begin
        if f = 'number' then
            begin
                test := to_number(v);
                self.result := 1;
                self.resulttext := null;
                return;
                exception when VALUE_ERROR then
                    self.result := 0;
                    self.resulttext := 'Invalid number. Valid formats are: 12345, 12345.67, -12345, etc...';
                    return;
            end;
        elsif f = 'phone' then
            null; --TO DO
        elsif f = 'integer' then
            null; --TO DO
        elsif f = 'email' then
            null; --TO DO
        elsif f = 'IPv4' then
            null; --TO DO
        elsif f = 'IPv6' then
            null; --TO DO
        end if;
        --dozens of others to follow....
    end;
end;
/
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include both implementations.  In addition, let us know exactly what version of Oracle you're using and what PL/SQL optimization level you're using.  Those details are going to be important.

Comment: the second one is a function?  you have: isValid2(x,'number').result  Maybe a copy/paste error?  Do you just want to know if a given string can be converted to a number?

Comment: It is a function, they both return an object. @JustinCave I'm adding the details you asked for to the question now...

Comment: It may have something to do with how Oracle is building the deterministic cache under the hood.  This is not a good place for a deterministic function because there are soooooo many different values  which will be passed into these functions, there is no way oracle will be able to build the hash map cache for every user.

Comment: Yeah. I think I'm starting to grasp it. So you should only use it when the function accepts a relatively small number of different combinations of variable values. So it can take them, run the function, cache the result, then if those same exact values are passed in again it will not run the logic in the function. Correct?

Comment: Do you have an actual performance problem that you're trying to fix?